# element disappearing when moved

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to reorder a list of rows in a table with javascript. I thought that I would just

1. create a dummy element
2. add all the rows to that element
3. add all the rows back to the original container in the right order

the rows, by the way, are picked up by javascript with getElementsByClassName (all of them have class name "sortrow"). The problem here was that the moment i start moving the elements, they disappear from the rows array, I guess I could add them back to the list by another getElementsByClassName but the order in which they are moved away might not be the same as the order they were first presented (so messes up indexing in the script).

Then i tried to just set the container innerHTML to nothing and then readding them but same thing happens, they dissapear from the array.

I'm not sure what to do here, how can I move them around while keeping references to them in js?

Also trying to keep this jquery free.

Comment: So, You want us to guess the problem or can you show the code?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is a dynamic collection, meaning its updated as things change. Your approach will have to take that into account.

Comment: @torazaburo thanks, I always thought it was just an array. Anyway, now when I copy the results of getElementsByClassName to an array they no longer disappear and my first approach works great.